# Remove locale from NFC record

Tags: flutter, dart, nfc

I want to pass a text value from my NFC tag to a variable, but want to remove the locale from the text passed to the variable (note, not remove it from the tag).

I am using the nfc_manager package.

Here is the code portion I am using that relates to scanning the tag:

```
NfcManager.instance.startSession(
    onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {

        final ndef = Ndef.from(tag);
        String tagRecordText = String.fromCharCodes(ndef!.cachedMessage!.records[0].payload);
        NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first byte is the length of the characters of the language string

So this should work (my dart is not that good)

```
var payload = ndef!.cachedMessage!.records[0].payload;
var sub = payload.sublist(payload[0]+ 1);
String tagRecordText = String.fromCharCodes(sub);
```

The detail specs of a [Text Record](https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-RTD_Text_1.0.pdf)

Comment: This does not work. I get the error "The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'." This is with the int.parse(payload[0]);

I will have a look at this document, thanks. Appreciate it.


I tweaked this slightly to 'int size = payload[0];' When doing this I get the error "Cannot remove from a fixed-length list"

Comment: Forgot to check the type returned as the payload was a `final Uint8List`, so updated to create a new Uint8List from the payload, beginning at the right point. Try again (I said my dart is not good)